# Convert 12 hour format date into 24 hour in XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to convert the date from 12 hour format to 24 hour format.

**Input:**
01/27/2016 07:01:36 PM

**Expected output:**
201601271901(YYYYMMDDHHMM)

I have used format-dateTime() function in my code ,I am getting error

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(part_need/promised_dt,'[Y0001][M01][D01][H01][m01]')"/>
```

Error:

Description: FORG0001: Invalid dateTime value "01/27/2016 07:01:36 PM" (Non-numeric year component)

Please help on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is not a valid ISO 8601 date/time, so you cannot use the built-in date/time functions on it.

Try instead something like (XSLT 2.0):

```
<xsl:template match="inputdate">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="dte" select="tokenize(.,'/|\s|:')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$dte[3]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$dte[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$dte[2]" />
        <xsl:variable name="h24" select="xs:integer($dte[4]) mod 12 + 12 * xs:integer($dte[7]='PM')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h24, '00')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$dte[5]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes your days are zero-padded to two digits (as are your months).

If you need to use this in several places, consider turning it into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

[format-dateTime](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/fn/format-dateTime.html) takes an `xs:dateTime?` as the first parameter. The `part_needed/promised_dt` is a `node`.

If you have the date-time in the standard ISO format (e.g. "2006-01-27T19:01:36"), you can use `xs:dateTime(part_needed/promised_dt)`.

Saxon does not have a non-standard date-time parser helper, so you would need to use the `xs:dateTime(xs:date(year,month,day), xs:time(hours, minutes, seconds))` constructor and use something like `substring(part_needed/promised_dt,1,2)` to get each date/time part.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the issue. I will try the above function